# No qualifying bean of type EntityManagerFactory is defined

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I wanted to create a generic DAO until I found that there is already `Spring data` which hundle this.
Before I worked with `hibernate`+`spring` and all it's work normally, I found this [tuto](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-one-configuration/) and i just add this line at my configuration (`hibernate`+`spring`):

```
    <jpa:repositories base-package="repository"/>
```

But i got this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'loginC': Injection of resource dependencies failed
Error creating bean with name 'authRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed
No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
```

I think it's a JPA problem because i always use hibernate.

My hibernateContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="dao"/>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>database.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> -->
        </props>

    </property>
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

My servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="repository"/>
```

My repository interface:

```
public interface AuthRepository extends JpaRepository<Auth, Integer> {}
```

My controller `loginC`:

```
@Resource
private AuthRepository authRepository;


@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "welcome")
public String printWelcome() {

    authRepository.save(new Auth("spring", "data"));

    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you have no defined Spring bean of type EntityManagerFactory. You defined a SessionFactory, but it's irrelevant.

Comment: I'm new at jpa stuff can you explain me more because i worked with hibernate before and i didn't need this bean `EntityManagerFactory` i used `sessionFactory`.

Comment: SessionFactory is used when you use the proprietary Hibernate API. To use JPA, you need an EntityManagerFactory. The Spring documentation explains how to create one.

Comment: Thanks now i undestand :) but we can't use just JPA we need to have a provider ? because i got this error `No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration`

Comment: JPA is just an API, like JDBC. You need an implementation (Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA, etc.), just like you need a JDBC driver.